# Kill a process using a handle Win32

Tags: winapi, wpf-4.0, win32-process

Hi I have a simple requirement to kill a process or get a process using the Handle.

I tried getting the process using handle but i don't see any good API that does that. 
Alternately I tried getting all active processes by `Process.GetProcesses()` 
looped through each process to see if they match the handle but it throws exception when trying to access some handles. So I guess that's not the best way.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Look at that codeproject article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21926/Getting-Process-ID-from-Process-Handle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried `GetProcessesByName()` method

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("your.exe"))
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
```

Comment: This would give me multiple processes if there are multiple instances. I dont want that way